# How to make user NOT see own name in list of users in socket chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm building a simple chat using this [guide](http://www.tamas.io/simple-chat-application-using-node-js-and-socket-io/).

When someone login their name is appended to the list of online users. However, each user should not see his/her own name in the list, only the name of the other users. Any suggestions to what I should add/change in my code to fix this?

client-side:

```js
socket.on("update-people", function(data, id){
          $("#people").empty();
          $.each(data.people, function(a, obj, id) {
              $('#people').append("<li class=\"people-item\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"list-group-item\"><span class="+obj.id+">" + obj.name + "</span></a></li>");
          });
        });

        socket.on("update-people-withSelf", function(people){
          $('#people').append("<li class=\"people-item\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"list-group-item\"><span class="+people.id+">" + people.name + "</span></a></li>");
        });
```

server-side:

```js
// Setting up the server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var socket = require("socket.io").listen(server);
var Room = require('./room.js');
var Conversation = require('./conversation.js');
var _ = require('underscore')._;
var uuid = require ('uuid');
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server is running...');

socket.set("log level", 1);
var people = {};  
var rooms = {};
var conversations = {};
var clients = [];
var chatHistory = {};

Array.prototype.contains = function(k, callback) {  
    var self = this;
    return (function check(i) {
        if (i >= self.length) {
            return callback(false);
        }
        if (self[i] === k) {
            return callback(true);
        }
        return process.nextTick(check.bind(null, i+1));
    }(0));
};



// Gets the html file
app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

// Gets the css file
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// When connecting
socket.on("connection", function(client) {
 client.on("join", function(name){
  client.emit("update-people", {people: people});
  sizePeople = _.size(people);
  socket.sockets.emit("update-peopleCount", {people: people, count: sizePeople});
  var ownerRoomID = inRoomID = null;
  roomID = null;
  conversationID = null; // This line probably has to go, since users should be able to create several conversations.
  people[client.id] = {"name" : name, "owns" : ownerRoomID, "inroom" : inRoomID, "id" : client.id, "room" : roomID, "conversation" : conversationID};
  var id = uuid.v4();
  //sizePeople = _.size(people);
  sizeRooms = _.size(rooms);
  sizeConversations = _.size(conversations);
  //socket.sockets.emit("update-peopleCount", {people: people, count: sizePeople});
  //socket.sockets.emit("update-people", {people: people});
  socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms, count: sizeRooms});
  socket.sockets.emit("update-conversations", {conversations: conversations, count: sizeConversations});
  client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have connected to the server. Start conversation or create/join room to chat");
  client.broadcast.emit('updateToOthers', name + " is online.");
  clients.push(client); //populates the clients array with the client object
  console.log("Someone joined the chat", people[client.id].id);
  //client.broadcast.emit("sendingOwnName", people[client.id].id);
  client.broadcast.emit("update-people-withSelf", people[client.id]);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I have updated my question with the correct code. 
Basically what was needed was an update of users BEFORE the new user is given an id, name ect. Afterwards, that new user broadcast his/her name to the other users.

Answer (score 0):

If those people have some id assigned to them, then you can have
condition in your loop to not append user him/herself.
`if(obj.id !== currentUser.id) { $'#people').append(... }`
Of course you can also use user name or some other info.

Comment: Won't I need to use 'broadcast' to make sure a users can't see its own name? Where should your code be appended?

Comment: I have tried with:socket.on("update-people", function(data){
          $("#people").empty();
          $.each(data.people, function(a, obj, id) {
            if (people[client.id].name == obj.name ) {
              return;
            } else {
              $('#people').append("<li class=\"people-item\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"list-group-item\"><span class="+obj.name+""+obj.id+">" + obj.name + "</span></a></li>");
            }
          });
        });    But doesn't work